QED: Structure of electron vertex function in the massless limit
I am working my way through Peskin & Schröder's "Introduction to QFT". In section 6.2, the formal structure of the electron vertex function $\Gamma^\mu$ is considered. From Lorentz invariance, and by the Ward identity, it is found that it must be of the form (eq. 6.31)
$$
\Gamma^\mu=A\gamma^\mu + B(p^\mu+p'^\mu).\tag{6.31}
$$
When doing the calculation explicitly to first loop order, in section 6.3, it is found (eq. 6.54) to have the expected structure:
$$
\Gamma^\mu=\gamma^\mu + \frac{\alpha}{2\pi}\int dxdydz\delta(x+y+z-1)\left(\gamma^\mu\left[\ldots\right]+\frac{i\sigma^{\mu\nu}q_\nu}{2}\left[\frac{1}{\Delta}mz(1-z)\right]\right).\tag{6.54}
$$
Here $p^\mu+p'^\mu$ has been traded for $2m\gamma^\mu-i\sigma^{\mu\nu}q_\nu$ using the Gordon identity (eq. 6.32)
$$
2m\,\bar u(p')\gamma^\mu u(p)=\bar u(p')\left[(p^\mu+p'^\mu)+i\sigma^{\mu\nu}q_\nu\right].\tag{6.32}
$$
In the massless $m=0$ limit, the term in $i\sigma^{\mu\nu}q_\nu$ vanishes, and the Gordon identity becomes
$$
0=\bar u(p')\left[(p^\mu+p'^\mu)+i\sigma^{\mu\nu}q_\nu\right]\;,
$$
and therefore the $(p^\mu+p'^\mu)$-term in the original structure also vanishes, i.e. $B=0$, and
$$
\Gamma^\mu = A\gamma^\mu
$$
My question is the following: is it generally true, to all orders, that $B=0$ in the massless limit? Or does this just happen to be true in the first loop order?

The form factor you wrote in terms of A and B is exact to all loop orders, because all that went into it was the symmetries of the relevant fields (which is non-perturbative information). Additionally, the Gordon identity is exact because it is a kinematic statement, and loops are telling you about dynamics. The thing the loops do is change what the values of A,B are perturbatively in an expansion of $\alpha$. It's more common to use the Gordon identity from the beginning to let the two operators in the form factor be $A\gamma^\mu$ and $B\sigma^{\mu\nu}q_\nu$, so I'll use that convenient from now on.
So if we can find an argument which argues that $B=0$ in the massless case, we are done. The thing that got us the form factor in the first place was considering the symmetry of the fields, so it's natural to expect a further restriction as coming from an enhanced symmetry in the massless limit. In fact, there is an enhanced symmetry in the massless limit: chiral symmetry. A massless Dirac fermion decomposes into two uncoupled (at tree level, at least) Weyl fermions of opposite chirality. We can rotate the phases of these fields independently, which is more symmetry than if they had a mass. That's because a mass term would couple these two fermions at tree level, explicitly breaking the chiral symmetry.
Using this extra chiral symmetry, you can argue that $B=0$ because the magnetic moment would break it. A rough sketch of this argument is that because the magnetic field is a pseudo-vector, a non-zero vev for the magnetic moment if a fermion is also a pseudo-vector, and pseudo-vectors explicitly break chiral symmetry because they pick out a preferred handedness.
Note that because chiral symmetry is anomalous, this argument relied crucially on there being zero background field (more generally, being on a background with vanishing flux $F \wedge F$). You might, therefore, expect that massless fermions dynamically generate a magnetic moment if there was a non-zero background field. But that's exactly what happens! Finally, I'll point out that it looks like this paper (and references therein) also briefly talks about the zero background field case as well if you want to read more.

Ok, so could a "formal proof" look something like this?
COM frame => photon spin =+/- 1 => electorn must flip spin. Since it also flips momentum, helicity is conserved.
For a massless electron, helicity = chirality. We thus expect
$$\gamma^5 u(p)=\pm u(p)=\gamma^5 u(p')$$
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\pm \bar u(p) [A\gamma^\mu +B(p^\mu+p'^\mu)]u(p')&=u^\dagger(p){\gamma^5}^\dagger\gamma^0[A\gamma^\mu+B(p^\mu+p'^\mu)]u(p') \
&=u^\dagger(p)[A\gamma^\mu-B(p^\mu+p'^\mu)]\gamma^5 u(p')\
&= \pm \bar u(p) [A\gamma^\mu -B(p^\mu+p'^\mu)]u(p')
\end{align*}
=> $B=0$
